# How to create new security groups in Labware software?

Tags: security

Please help me to understand how security groups are created that can be assigned to users in Labware LIMS software and where it is stored in database?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but this doesn't feel like it's programming related. Labware LIMS seems to be some lab management software, which makes this look like a application user question (which is offtopic on this site).

Comment: I agree with Joachim Sauer this is not programming related. Should probably consult the Labware LIMS user manual or helpdesk.

Answer (score 0):

There is a record in the LIST table called GROUP which is an out of the box record. This record contains all the security groups that the system uses. If you add an entry to this record that should do the trick.

Also, this is very standard functionality to LabWare LIMS since at least V5. You can find more information in the LabWare Technical Manual for your version. 
That being said, the comment on your question is correct. We have a mailing list that is available to our customers for questions exactly like this!

HTH